Docker build command failing:
docker-compose.yml: 
[+] Building 1.2s (11/11) FINISHED                         docker:desktop-linux

 => [regform internal] load build definition from Dockerfile               0.0s

 => => transferring dockerfile: 158B                                       0.0s

 => [early-deliverable-backend internal] load build definition from Docke  0.0s

 => => transferring dockerfile: 333B                                       0.0s

 => [pspage internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                0.0s

 => => transferring dockerfile: 158B                                       0.0s

 => [excelreader internal] load build definition from Dockerfile           0.0s

 => => transferring dockerfile: 158B                                       0.0s

 => [springapp internal] load build definition from Dockerfile             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 333B                                       0.0s

 => [early-deliverable-frontend internal] load build definition from Dock  0.0s

 => => transferring dockerfile: 275B                                       0.0s

 => WARN: FromAsCasing: 'as' and 'FROM' keywords' casing do not match (li  0.0s

 => [login internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                 0.0s

 => => transferring dockerfile: 158B                                       0.0s

 => CANCELED [regform internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx  1.2s

 => CANCELED [early-deliverable-frontend internal] load metadata for dock  1.2s

 => CANCELED [early-deliverable-frontend internal] load metadata for dock  1.2s

 => ERROR [early-deliverable-backend internal] load metadata for docker.i  1.1s

------
  [early-deliverable-backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17-    alpine3.14:
------
failed to solve: openjdk:17-alpine3.14: failed to resolve source metadata for 

docker.io/library/openjdk:17-alpine3.14: no match for platform in manifest: not found


although we can guess what your question is, it would be nice if you take more effort to present your problem.

The openjdk:17-alpine3.14 image is only available for the linux/amd64 platform and not the Mac ARM architecture.
The openjdk image is deprecated as announced here and you should consider using one of the other images listed.
